# Get Elements by Tag Name from a Node in Android (XML) Document?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML like this:

```
  <!--...-->
  <Cell X="4" Y="2" CellType="Magnet">
    <Direction>180</Direction>
    <SwitchOn>true</SwitchOn>
    <Color>-65536</Color>
  </Cell>
  <!--...-->
```

There're many `Cell elements`, and I can get the Cell Nodes by `GetElementsByTagName`. However, I realise that `Node` class DOESN'T have `GetElementsByTagName` method! How can I get `Direction` node from that cell node, without go throught the list of `ChildNodes`? Can I get the `NodeList` by Tag name like from `Document` class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can cast the `NodeList` item again with `Element` and then use `getElementsByTagName();` from `Element` class.
The best approach is to make a `Cell Object` in your project alongwith fields like `Direction`, `Switch`, `Color`. Then get your data something like this.

```
String direction [];
NodeList cell = document.getElementsByTagName("Cell");
int length = cell.getLength();
direction = new String [length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Element element = (Element) cell.item(i);
    NodeList direction = element.getElementsByTagName("Direction");

    Element line = (Element) direction.item(0);

    direction [i] = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);

    // remaining elements e.g Switch , Color if needed
}
```

Where your `getCharacterDataFromElement()` will be as follow.

```
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e)
{
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData)
    {
        CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
        return cd.getData();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot Node can be cast to Element! Happy coding :)